# How to have to two different versions of Java on the same computer in OS X

Tags: macos, mac, java

I got an iMac with OS X 10.11.2 El Capitan. I have installed the latest version of Java SE. However, I have a problem with running some Max for Live effects because Max for Live requires Java SE6 in order to be able to run.

On an Ableton forum, one of the users mentioned that he used two different versions of Java, the latest and SE6, he then switches to the latter when needing to use Max for Live.

I have downloaded from the Apple site, a Java for OS X 2015-001 which would install Java SE6, however I'm concerned that if I install it in the normal fashion it will override Java SE8.

I want to know how I can install Java SE6, but still keeping Java SE8 and how I can switch between versions when necessary.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try `jenv` util to use different versions for different apps: [link to how-to](http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/install-multiple-jdk-on-mac/)

In general, you should download all the versions you need, then you've gotta do the following:

- install **jenv** (this step require any **brew** instance on your mac, if you don't have one, look [here](http://brew.sh/)):

  `brew install jenv`
- add these lines to your `.bash_profile`, script will init **jenv** util:

  `# Init jenv
  if which jenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(jenv init -)"; fi`
- register all jdk in ***jenv*:

`jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/
 jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/`

- run this to list all registered jdk:

`jenv versions`

One with the asterisk is the current version.

- this command'll set **global** version:

`jenv global oracle64-1.7.0.79`

- and by this one you can set **local** versions in any project folders you need:

`cd <my project>
jenv local oracle64-1.8.0.66`